# UWP TextBox write numbers in it when scrolled horizontally with touchpad

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, textbox, touchpad

I have a **TextBox** in my app in which I tried to check horizontal scrolling with my touch pad, and when I double finger scroll right the textbox adds number **4** to its text per scroll towards right direction. And when I scroll left it writes 6 to it.

```
<TextBox Text="{x:Bind Description, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

There is no complicated login behind it, just a normal textbox. Also note that when I scroll really hard in 1 swipe (which usually scrolls something to the end), it writes a lot of numbers in a quick succession.

Why is this happening, and how can I stop it?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] to show what you've done.

Comment: @XavierXie-MSFT the minimal example is an empty uwp app with a textbox in it, nothing else.

Comment: I could not reproduce the scenario `when I double finger scroll right the textbox adds number 4 to its text per scroll towards right direction. And when I scroll left it writes 6 to it. when I scroll really hard in 1 swipe (which usually scrolls something to the end), it writes a lot of numbers in a quick succession.` in an empty uwp app with a textbox.